# Does using proguard makes the android app running slower?

Tags: android, proguard

I developed an app and obfuscated it with proguard. However it worked, but it seems the application now run slower than the previous before obfuscation.
Need help !!

Answer (score 2):

Especially on Android's Dalvik VM, processed applications should be faster. If you have a simple example that runs more slowly, you can mail it to me and I'll look into it ([ProGuard feedback page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/feedback.html)).

Comment: Is it like excluding/including  the R class file in an android app from proguard configuration  may affect the performance ??

Comment: I don't think that could make a difference.

Comment: I'm getting about 10-20% increase in FPS after applying pro-guard.